# Vue3 Props v-if sync

Tags: vuejs3

I'm making props with vue, but v-if doesn't work, and I'm wondering if the functions I've done are written correctly.
I want the data from props to work synchronously. What are my mistakes made?

What functions does vue props check at startup?

`<my-alert type="warning" appearance="outline" showIcon="false">Hello</my-alert>`

myAlert.vue

```
<template>
<div class="block" :class="[typeClass,appearanceClass]">
    <div class="alert-icon" v-if="myIcon">
      <i>ICON</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
const types =
    ['primary','accent','warn','basic','info','success','warning','error',
    ];
const appearances =
    ['border','accent','fill','outline','soft'];

import {defineComponent} from "vue";
import {computed} from "vue";

export default {
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'primary',
      required: true,
      validator: value => {
        return ['primary', 'accent', 'warn', 'basic', 'info', 'success', 'warning', 'error'].includes(value)
      }
    },
    appearance: {
      type: String,
      default: 'border',
      required: true,
      validator: value => {
        return ['border', 'accent', 'fill', 'outline', 'soft'].includes(value)
      }
    },
    showIcon: {
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    typeClass() {
      return 'alert-type-' + this.type
    },
    appearanceClass() {
      return 'alert-appearance-' + this.appearance
    },
    myIcon() {
      return this.showIcon;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code what I can see, that you are passing the props shwoIcon like this `showIcon="false"`, which is static passing and eventually pass false value as a string "false" not as Boolean value. So use props like this `:shwoIcon="false"` I mean use colon before showIcon which make the props dynamic. [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props)

And Also in your `my-alert` component for showIcon props declear type for the  better practice

```
showIcon: {
   type: Boolean,
   default: false,
},
```

Another way is, just simply change your computed property `myIcon()` to check the string props value, like this below,

```
myIcon() {
    return this.showIcon === "true";
}
```

Comment: `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "showIcon". Expected Boolean, got String with value "false".`

Comment: Do you make your props dynamic as I said? use colon before showIcon props like this `<my-alert type="warning" appearance="outline" :showIcon="false">Hello</my-alert>`

Comment: I did as you said, it worked, but is it possible to run it without bind?

Comment: Yes then you have to change your `myIcon()` computed property and return like this ` return this.showIcon === "true" ` to check the showIcon's string value. **update my answer including this way**